# Writing TDD unit test for method that returns IEnumerable<IResult> (Caliburn Micro)

Tags: tdd, rhino-mocks, caliburn

I would like to know, how do I call a method that returns IEnumerable from within my unit test in Visual Studio 2010. I am using rhino mocks mocking framwork.

Comment: You'll need to specify a little more of what you're trying to do. "how do I call a method that returns IEnumerable…" -- same way as you call any other method.

Comment: I usually call by using coroutine.Execute(methodName.GetEnumerator()). But calling the method this way results into "Object reference not found exception".

Comment: Could you show some sample code?  What's the method signature you're writing a test for and what test code have you written that doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should be what you are looking for:

```
var expectedDatasets = new List<Dataset>{new Dataset()};
Expect.Call(service.FindDatasets()).Return(expectedDatasets);
```

Since a List implements the IEnumerable interface you will be able to say you expect it;